# How to convert amount of time into seconds?

Tags: ruby, time

Say it took someone 3 minutes and 45 seconds to complete a task.

I'd represent that as 3:45.

But what I need to do is, assuming I'm given `3:45`, convert that to the number of seconds it took.

So when given `3:45`, I want to convert that to `225`.

This would need to work with Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: I'd use multiplication. What about hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like Dave suggested, or if you need more stuff, there's a [duration library](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration) that does this stuff.

It would look like:

```
001:0> ChronicDuration.parse("3:45")
225
```

Comment: +1, much better idea (and a good gem to boot; this and chronic handle most of my time needs).

Answer (score 1):

I'd be careful about reinventing the wheel here. While you  may assume you'll have only minutes and seconds, and that you'll always have the same format, it's safer to have something more robust.

Check out [chronic_duration](https://github.com/hpoydar/chronic_duration), a gem for parsing elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

```
def time_to_seconds(str)

  time_in = []
  time_in = str.split(":").reverse
  asec = 0
  secs = [1, 60, 60*60, 60*60*24]

  time_in.size.times do {|i|
    asec += secs[i].to_i * time_in[i].to_i
  end
  sec
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class String
  def to_secs
    split(':').reverse.zip([1, 60, 60*60]).inject(0) { |m, e| m += e[0].to_i * e[1]  }
  end
end

puts '3:45'.to_secs  # 225
puts '1:03:45'.to_secs  # 3825
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pry(main)> a = "3:45".split(":")
=> ["3", "45"]
pry(main)> a[0].to_i*60 + a[1].to_i
=> 225
```

(Wrapped up in a method, of course.)

Comment: Using that, how do you account for the possible inclusion of an an hour (`1:37:49`)? Sometimes the hour will be there, other times it won't.

Comment: @Shpigford Check for array length. But I'm with Joel and Emily--there's zero reason to do this by hand.